# Request.get not rendering all 'hrefs' in HTML Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to fetch the "Contact Us" page of multiple websites. It works for some of the websites, but for some, the text rendered by request.get does not contain all the 'href" links. When i inspect the page in browser, it is visible but not coming through in requests.
Tried to look for the solution , but to no luck:-

Below is the code and the webpage i am trying to scrape https://portcullis.co/  :-

```
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
def page_contact(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    txt = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    links = []
    for link in txt.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    return r, links
```

The output generated is :-

```
<Response [200]> []
```

Since it is working fine for some other websites, i would prefer to edit it in a way where it doesn't just cater to this website, but to all websites,

Any help is highly appreciated !!
Thanks !!!

Comment: many websites add html via js, meaning that you wont get it when using requests. you might want to look into [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way to solve this using only selenium and not BeautifulSoup

```
        browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome.exe)
        browser.get(url)
        browser.set_page_load_timeout(100)
        time.sleep(3)             
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_tag_name("a"))
        time.sleep(20)
        elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') , 'contact')]")
        for el in elements:
            final_link.append(el.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would fetch you the source page info, and you can find the relevant links by passing it to beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'path to your chrome exe')
browser.get('Your url')
time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = browser.page_source
txt = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
browser.close()
links = []
for link in txt.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped !!